# Mysql not escaping backslashes and quotes the way they need to be

Tags: mysql, json

I'm trying to insert a json document into Mysql. I know it's not great but there's nothing I can do about that at the moment.

This is what my insert looks like:

```
insert into table_name (cid,def) values (1234, '{"field1": "field with \\\" char"}');
```

No matter what I do, what ends up being inserted is:

```
{"field1": "field with \\" char"}
```

But what I need is:

```
{"field1": "field with \" char"}
```

When I try:

```
insert into table_name (cid,def) values (1234, '{"field1": "field with \\" char"}');
```

It still ends up like this:

```
{"field1": "field with \\" char"}
```

For some reason, three backslashes and two backslashes both produce the same exact result: two backslashes being saved.

When I use NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES, every backslash gets stored as a double backslash, which is also not what I need.

If anyone has any ideas as to what may be going on, that would be fantastic. Everything I've found so far suggests that storing the field as \\\" should work, and intuitively that makes sense, but it is just not working.

Update: it seems like the root issue is that no matter what I do, a double backslash simply does not get escaped to a single backslash. For some reason, it just treats the double backslash and a double backslash.

Comment: show whatever code is doing this, e.g. your actual query string as generated in your host language, and the query calls. most likely you're not escaping properly.

Comment: have you tried add_slashes() ?

Comment: I can't do it in code, I'm trying to manually recover from an issue so I am actually just doing it via the mysql cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried with mysql 5.6. The data isn't stored incorrectly, you're likely just misinterpreting the output (the phrase "every backslash gets stored as a double backslash" increases my confidence in this).

```
mysql> insert into table_name (cid,def) values (1234, '{"field1": "field with \\
\" char"}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select *,length(def) from table_name;
+------+----------------------------------+-------------+
| cid  | def                              | length(def) |
+------+----------------------------------+-------------+
| 1234 | {"field1": "field with \" char"} |          32 |
+------+----------------------------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

$ python
>>> import mysql.connector as mysql
>>> cn=mysql.connect(<...>)
>>> c=cn.cursor()
>>> c.execute('select * from table_name;')
>>> c.fetchall()
[(1234, u'{"field1": "field with \\" char"}')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah, it was my mistake. The way I was checking the value of the data was by piping a file with the select statement into mysql, i.e. mysql < select.sql  The output of that was always showing two backslashes so I was pretty confounded but when I actually went in to mysql I saw that there was in fact only one backslash. I felt pretty silly when I saw that, I should have checked that way sooner.

Comment: @LizBennett string's length, as I demonstrated, is a good sanity check (both data's and yours ;) - when you start seeing two backslashes where there is one, things indeed look pretty grim =)) )